# How to quit preview mode in the editor?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using AucTex on emacs and when I hit `C-c C-p C-e` I am then unable to quite the preview mode. Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: You mean, how to remove the preview images?  In menu `Preview`, under the `Remove Previews` sections you'll find the buttons (with associated key bindings) to remove the previews.  Does it help?

Answer (score 3):

Try  M-x "preview-clearout" or "preview-clearout-buffer"